# how to valid my code jquery function on drupal 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-8

I would like to apply my `gray()` function to my img on my site.

I have installed my library in drupal 8, I can see my library in my `package.json` and I have declared it in my library file.

Here my code jquery:

```
(function ($) {

    $('img').gray();

}(jQuery));
```

But it's not working.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: show your `gray` jQuery plugin, or if it a simple function, that please

Comment: yes, my plugin function is this link : https://github.com/karlhorky/gray

Comment: Please add more information as this does not error as you have it posted

Answer (score 0):

You are using **self invoked function** which will be executed as soon as it is encountered in the Javascript. so sometimes DOM is not ready on this case.
Try to put your function call **inside document ready function**. document ready will be encountered after the dom ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('img').gray(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use drupal behaviours in your js code. Sometimes js got conflicted due to mixing of different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some other issue on your site as the code as you have posted works, adding this answer to show that it is.

Image borrowed from here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4389/139898

```js
(function ($) {

    $('img').gray();

 }(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/jquery-gray@1.6.0/css/gray.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery-gray@1.6.0/js/jquery.gray.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPfiX.jpg" alt="notfoundme"  class="grayscale"/>
```